# Vue directive not triggering method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a custom vue directive.

```
Vue.directive('click-outside', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {

    document.addEventListener(clickHandler, (event) => {
      const clickedInsideDropdown = el.contains(event.target);

      if (!clickedInsideDropdown && el.classList.contains(openClass)) {
        vnode.context.$emit(binding.expression);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I then initialize it with the dropdown template:

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown" :class="{ '-is-open': open }" v-click-outside="close">
    <span @click="toggle">
      <slot name="toggle"></slot>
    </span>
    <slot name="menu"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

The supporting logic is functioning as expected as well:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        open: false
      }
    },

    methods: {
      close: function () {
        this.open = false;
        console.log('close');
      },

      toggle: function () {
        this.open = !this.open;
        console.log('toggle');
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

#### The Problem

The event should fire when the current dropdown _is open and none of the items inside of it are clicked - which is does (console logging confirms this). However, the `$emit` is not triggering the `close` method for some reason.

- The event *is* being emitted in the Vue devtools as expected.
- Vue version `2.5.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to Linus Borg who [answered my question for me on the forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-directive-not-triggering-method/21469/2?u=austinpaquette). Was just understanding the purpose of events incorrectly.

> Events are usually used to communicate from a child component to a parent component, so triggering an event ‘close’ in a componet will not run a method of that name in that component.
>
> If you want that, you have to actually register a listener to that event:

```
created () {
  this.$on('close', this.close /*the name of the method to call */)
}
```

> However, this isn’t really necessary in your case. you are already passing the close method to the directive, so you can run it directly:

```
Vue.directive('click-outside', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {

    document.addEventListener(clickHandler, (event) => {
      const clickedInsideDropdown = el.contains(event.target);

      if (!clickedInsideDropdown && el.classList.contains(openClass)) {
        binding.value()

        // alternartively, you could also call the method directly on the instance, no need for an event: 
        vnode.context.[expression]()
        // but that wouldn't really be elegant, agreed?
      }
    });
  }
});
```